# Remove page numbering from first page of resume of letter module

Tags: page-numbering, context

A document like the modern sample on https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Curriculum_Vitae#Stripped_down_example contains page numbers even when only one page is generated.  Using `\setuppagenumbering[location=]` does not remove the page numbering.

How can this be done.  I am sure I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to clear the `renderingsetup` of the `resumelayeralternative`.  I don't blame you for not finding it.  It's not documented anywhere.  I was just browsing the [source code](http://minimals.contextgarden.net/current/modules/t-letter/tex/context/third/letter/base/s-cor-03.mkvi) to find it.

```
\setupresumelayeralternative
  [nextfoot:classic]
  [renderingsetup=]
```

Full MWE:

```
\usemodule[resume]

\setupresumelayeralternative
  [nextfoot:classic]
  [renderingsetup=]

%\useresumestyle[casual-blue]
\useresumestyle[classic-blue]

\setupresumeoptions
  [bodyfont=calluna]

\setupresume
  [firstname=John,
   familyname=Doe,
   title=Resumé title (optional),% classic style only
   quote=My quote,% casual style only
   image={\externalfigure[dummy][width=3cm,height=4cm]}]

\setupresume
  [street={street and number},
   town={postcode city},
   mobile={+1(234)567890},
   phone={+2(345)678901},
   fax={+3(456)789012},
   email={john@doe.org},
   info={additional information}]

\startresume

\startresumesection[title={Knuth}]

\startresumesubsection[title={Zapf}]

\starttwocolumns
\input ward
\stoptwocolumns

\stopresumesubsection

\stopresumesection

\page

\startresumesection[title={Knuth}]

\startresumesubsection[title={Zapf}]

\starttwocolumns
\input ward
\stoptwocolumns

\stopresumesubsection

\stopresumesection

\stopresume
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like all the header is missing now.  Also, I am using the casual style (but I will be able to adapt the answer, I am sure.)

Comment: @ibotty In the MWE in my answer there is no header even without `\setupresumelayeralternative`.  When using the casual style just use `nextfoot:casual` instead of `nextfoot:classic`.

Comment: Ah, I did not look closely!  Thank you.